# Select vowels from a varchar, Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to pull up the count of the vowels contained in a varchar,
I've been looking around in google, no success though.

Can anyone give me a hand with this one?

Comment: Count of vocals?  You mean characters?  Words?

Comment: Is it just the `length` of the varchar you are looking for? Boy it looks like we are asking more questions than you!

Comment: for instance... from 'andrew' -> 'ae'

Comment: I just need to know how many vowels there are in a varchar

Comment: Do you count `y` as a vowel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Oracle 11g, you can use the [REXEXP_COUNT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions147.htm#SQLRF20014) function to determine what matches the pattern.

```
SQL> select regexp_count('andrew', '[aeiou]', 1, 'i') as vowels
  2    from dual;

    VOWELS
----------
         2
```

The first parameter is the string you want to match, `'andrew'`.

The second parameter is the match pattern, in this case `[aeiou]`. The `[]` indicates a character list; the parser matches any and all characters inside this list in any order.

The third parameter, `1`, is the start position indicating the positional index of the string where Oracle should start searching for a match. It's included solely so I can use the fourth parameter.

The fourth parameter is a match parameter, `'i'` indicates that I want to do case insensitive matching. This is the reason why the character list is *not* `[aeiouAEIOU]`.

If you're using 10g then REGEXP_COUNT doesn't exist. In this case you could use a more exact version of [Annjawan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13753869/458741) with [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm#SQLRF06302).

```
SQL> select length(regexp_replace('andrew','[^aeiou]', '', 1, 0, 'i')) as vowels
  2    from dual;

    VOWELS
----------
         2
```

The carat (`^`) indicates a not, i.e. the replaces every character in the string `'andrew'` that is not in the character list `[aeiou]` with the empty string. The next parameter, once again, is the start position. The fifth parameter, `0` indicates that you want to replace *every* occurrence of the pattern that matches and once again I've used the match parameter `'i'` to indicate case insensitive matching.

[Gaurav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13753722/458741) is incorrect. This is because within the character list he has included comma's. Remember that *everything* within the character list get's matched if it is available. So, if I introduce a comma into your string you'll have 3 "vowels" in your string:

```
SQL> select regexp_count('an,drew','[a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U]' ) as vowels
  2    from dual;

    VOWELS
----------
         3
```

Regular expressions are not simple beasts and I would highly recommend reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_regexp.htm) when attempting them.

Comment: you have not handled Upper case in your statement for eg. this - `select length(regexp_replace('AndrEw','[^aeiou]', '', 1, 0, 'c')) as vowels from dual;` returns `NULL`.

Comment: That'd be because `c` is the operator for case-sensitive matching not case-insensitive... it should have been `i` @Annjawn.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
select length(regexp_replace('andrew','[^AEIOUaeiou]')) as vowels from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT length('andrew')
          - length(REGEXP_REPLACE('andrew','[a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U]','')) 
FROM DUAL;
```

Output:2 -- `a` and `e` are two vowels here.

If you are using Oracle 11g  then

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT('andrew','[a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U]' ) from dual
```

Comment: Thank you @Gaurav Soni

I'll leave a solution I just made here,

with T as (select nombre as txt FROM EMPLEADOS)
--
SELECT txt, regexp_count(txt,'[^aeiou ]' ) as cons_count
      ,regexp_count(txt,'[aeiou]' ) as vowel_count
from T

;)